# Frame diplay Issue: 1st Frame content gets hide behing 2nd frame

Tags: html, frameset

```
<head>
    <title>Lead Management System</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="13%,*,3%" border="0" frameborder="0" style="z-index:4">
<frame name="navigation" target="main" src="navigation.php" scrolling="No" style="z-index:100"> 
<frameset cols="18%,*" border="0" frameborder="0">
    <frame name="menu" target="main" src="menu.php" scrolling="No" style="z-index:10">
    <frame name="main" src="start.php" scrolling="auto" noresize style="z-index:11">
</frameset>
<frame name="footer" target="main" src="footer.php" scrolling="No" style="z-index:12">
</frameset>
```

Also i had tried z-index concept for it but it didn't help me at all..So please is there any way that my 1st frame content should always be on top of second frame if there is any dropdown or other fields which does not gets fit in its own 1st frame.
I also referd some questions already in stackverflow but i was not able to solve it...

Comment: fiddle your code. that will help more to solve this problem.